# Force between two point charges lying in different media

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

Consider, as in the following picture, two point charges $q$ and $Q$, the former lying in (say) air, and the latter in water. The charges cannot move. What is the force exerted by each of the two charges on the other?

[image]

I know this has been asked before, but I don’t find the answers given particularly helpful (neither did the authors of the posts apparently, since none was accepted).